# php date give me the same date for 2 different timestamp

Tags: php, date

here my code :

```
<?php
    $aaa = array(
        1224972000,
        1224973800,
        1224975600,
        1224977400,
        1224979200,
        1224981000,
        1224982800,
        1224984600,
        1224986400,
        1224988200,
        1224990000,
        1224991800,
        1224993600,
        1224995400,
        1224997200,
    );
    foreach ($aaa as $ts) {
        $date = \date('m/d/Y,H:i:s', $ts);
        echo "$date \n";
    }

And the result is :
10/26/2008,00:00:00
10/26/2008,00:30:00
10/26/2008,01:00:00
10/26/2008,01:30:00
**10/26/2008,02:00:00
10/26/2008,02:30:00
10/26/2008,02:00:00
10/26/2008,02:30:00**
10/26/2008,03:00:00
10/26/2008,03:30:00
10/26/2008,04:00:00
10/26/2008,04:30:00
10/26/2008,05:00:00
10/26/2008,05:30:00
10/26/2008,06:00:00
```

Why ?

Comment: And whats wrong with that?

Comment: What result are you expecting more than this?

Comment: In what time zone are you located at (or your server)? 26th oct. 2008 was the date when DST was off in Russia / Australian and some other countries which I won't bother to list. It appears you've gotten your results because of that.

Comment: nothing wrong here http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/bpd-1sm

Answer (score 4):

I'd imagine that in your chosen timezone, the date switches from Daylight Savings Time on that day, so there are two 2:00ams. I see you're studying in Liverpool -- would this be on a British machine? Last Sunday in October is traditionally the shift date between British Summer Time and Greenwich Mean Time. I believe that would also be the case for most of Europe.

Try adding:

```
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
```

at the start of your script; that will fix the timezone to one without DST adjustments. You should find you get unique results.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what timezone you are in!

For your area the daylight saving times probably end in last Sunday of an October each year OR that is how it was in 2008.

So, different time stamps represent the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I've my answer :
my server give me
reno@ubuntu:~$ date -d @1224979200
dimanche 26 octobre 2008, 02:00:00 (UTC+0200)
reno@ubuntu:~$ date -d @1224982800
dimanche 26 octobre 2008, 02:00:00 (UTC+0100)

and the reason is
http://www.lecalendrier.fr/changement-d-heure-2008

I'm so stupid

Comment: So basically, you got your answer after about 4 people told you why :) good job.

Comment: -1 because: you ignored the other, correct answers AND you linked to a french resource on an english website

Comment: It's because you're too fast to answer.

Comment: Jeannot at least have the decency to accept @MattGibson's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18443244/998759